# How to do some operation when Optional has null value?

Tags: java, java-stream, option-type

In my stream I want to get MainMenuOption based on user's input. If enum MainMenuOptions contains such option I want to return it, if not - print some message "THERE IS NO SUCH OPTION" and get user's input again.

```
return Arrays.stream(MainMenuOptions.values())
            .filter(x -> x.getCommand().equals(ConsoleInput.getNextLineFromUser()))
            .findFirst() // it returns Optional<MainMenuOptions>
            .orElse(); //or Else return some value, cannot do something
```

How I can achive it with Java Steams?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: A thought, return the `Optional<MainMenuOptions>` and leave to the caller to print any message. The caller may for example use `ifPresentOrElse()` (since Java 9).

Comment: You can throw custom exception and ask user to select again if it raise `orElseThrow(()->new MenuOptionNotFoundException())`

Comment: These solutions are also good. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a `Optional.map` operation before `orElse` to transform to `Optional<String>` such as

```
return Arrays.stream(MainMenuOptions.values())
        .filter(x -> x.getCommand().equals(ConsoleInput.getNextLineFromUser()))
        .findFirst()
        .map(MainMenuOptions::name)
        .orElse("THERE IS NO SUCH OPTION");
```

Comment: Thank you for help.